# PHP - For loop only returns last variable in array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a strange problem where a for loop in PHP only returns the last item in my array.

The array is created with SimpleXML from an XML file.

The code should return this:

```
<tags><tag value="Tag1" /><tag value="Tag2" /><tag value="Tag3" /></tags>
```

But instead I just get:

```
<tags><tag value="Tag3" /></tags>
```

So it ignores all but the last item in the array no matter how many I got in there.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
<?php

function gettags($xml)
{
    $xmltags = $xml->xpath('//var[@name="infocodes"]/string');
    return $xmltags[0];
}

//Path to the XML files on the server
$path = "/xmlfiles/";

//Create an array with all the XML files
$files = glob("$path/*.xml");

foreach($files as $file)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $xmltags = gettags($xml);

//Using the , character split the values coming from the $xmltags into an array
$rawtags = explode(',', $xmltags);

//Loop through the tags and add to a variable. Each tag will be inside an XML element - <tag value="tagname" />
for ($i = 0; $i <count($rawtags); $i++){
    $tags = '<tag value="' . $rawtags[$i] . '" />';
}

//Replace HTML escaped characters (ä, å, ö, Å, Ä, Ö) and the | character with normal characters in the tags variable
$tagsunwantedchars = array("&Ouml;", "&Auml;", "&Aring;", "&ouml;", "&auml;", "&aring;", "|");
$tagsreplacewith = array("Ö", "Ä", "Å", "ö", "ä", "å", " - ");
$tagsclean = str_replace($tagsunwantedchars, $tagsreplacewith, $tags);

//Create the full tag list and store in a variable
$taglist = "<tags>$tagsclean</tags>";

}

echo $taglist;

?>
```

Here's the XML file:

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'>
    <header/>
    <data>
        <struct>
            <var name='infocodes'>
                <string>Tag1,Tag2,Tag3</string>
            </var>
        </struct>
    </data>
</wddxPacket>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple bug: use `$tags .=` instead of `$tags =` in the loop:

```
$tags = '';
for ($i = 0; $i <count($rawtags); $i++){
    $tags .= '<tag value="' . $rawtags[$i] . '" />';
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `$tags[] = ...`, then `implode` after the loop. It should be a little more performant.

Comment: It's also a good idea to initialize `$tags` before appending to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <count($rawtags); $i++){
    $tags = '<tag value="' . $rawtags[$i] . '" />';
}
```

You're just overwriting the `$tags` variable on every iteration. Try:

```
$tags = '';
foreach ($rawtags as $rawtag) {
    $tags .= '<tag value="' . $rawtag . '" />';
}
```

Note that you should initialize `$tags` before appending to it (otherwise it will generate a PHP warning).

Also, using `foreach` instead of a `for` loop makes your code simpler and more readable. Trivial errors like this are easier to spot when they aren't surrounded by noise.